# Add parent heading of source code block as comment in tangled file

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming, tangle

If I have something like this:

```
* Function heading

  #+begin_src racket :var x=3 y=4 :tangle "file.rkt"
  (define (distance x y)
    (sqrt (+ (sqr x) (sqr y))))
  (distance x y)
  #+end_src
```

How do I make the **parent** heading (in this example it's 'Function heading') show as a comment above the function in the tangled file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include the preceding text of a source block in a tangled file, you can use the header argument with the following option `:comments org`.

Per heading

```
* Function heading
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :comments org
:END:

  #+begin_src racket :var x=3 y=4 :tangle "file.rkt"
  (define (distance x y)
    (sqrt (+ (sqr x) (sqr y))))
  (distance x y)
  #+end_src
```

or per file via

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :comments org

* Function heading

  #+begin_src racket :var x=3 y=4 :tangle "file.rkt"
  (define (distance x y)
    (sqrt (+ (sqr x) (sqr y))))
  (distance x y)
  #+end_src
```

You can find more details [here](https://org-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/header-args/#comments)

Comment: I accepted the answer as it is, but it fails to copy over the headings that start with a `*`. I want that Heading to copy over as a comment above the function. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you maybe give an example for "headings that start with a `*`" and headings that don't?

Comment: And have you tried the per-file property shown above?

Comment: Yes I did. I just meant a normal heading. In this example I want `* Function heading` to be a comment above the function in the tangled output; just like how quote blocks and text become comments in the tangled file.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want the leading stars of a heading in the comment of the tangled file? e.g.: `;; * Function heading` as a comment for a first level heading and `;; ** Function heading subtree` for a second level heading (in an elisp file)? If so, I do not know the answer.

Comment: Yes, I want the heading, then the source code block underneath; and another heading and its source code block. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but what you describe should be the case for a per file property as shown in the answer above.

Comment: There was a typo in the `#+PROPERTY:` line (that I fixed): those pesky colons are confusing. I think you get the headline text but not the asterisks with `:comments org` (and I think there is a bug in upstream Org mode: it works as described in 9.5.5 but I cannot get *any* comment with the upstream version - OTOH, `:comments link` works with both versions). I imagine that if you *really* want the asterisks, you are going to have to fork Org mode and have it insert them somehow. But it does not seem useful enough to include in general, so I don't think an enhancement request would get traction.

Comment: The bug described in the above comment (`:comments org` did not produce *any* comments in Org mode 9.6 or later) has been fixed upstream - see [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=79ec91584c24264f83223192e5b18730b1a89b71) and [subequent fixup](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=f56ca5009ef3c83ed2862b76660911f5f389d8c1).